# Ruby on Rails 4 exceptions: how to bypass if field is blank

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, twilio

I have a form for my `Subscription` model and users have the option to enter a phone number. The Twilio API is being used.

```
class Subscription < ActiveRecord::Base

    validates_numericality_of :phone_number, allow_blank: true
    validate :mobile_phone_number

    def mobile_phone_number
        lookup_client = Twilio::REST::LookupsClient.new Rails.application.secrets.twilio_sid, Rails.application.secrets.twilio_token
        begin
            response = lookup_client.phone_numbers.get("#{self.phone_number}")
            response.phone_number #if invalid, throws an exception. If valid, no problems.
            return true
        rescue => e
            errors.add(:base, "That phone number is not valid.")
        end
    end
```

What is occurring: I can only enter valid phone numbers given the Twilio lookup API...this is a good thing. However, users need to be able to enter a BLANK phone number.

Currently, the `validates_numericality_of` method is getting overwritten by the `mobile_phone_number` method.

If I enter a blank phone_number, "That phone number is not valid" gets returned. This should not be happening.

How do I make a special case for the `rescue`? For example, "rescue this unless phone number is blank". Or what am I doing wrong here?

All input is appreciated.

Comment: `validate :mobile_phone_number, if: "phone_number.present?"`

Comment: You can as well define ruby methods as `def method_name rescue end`(multiline will look better) and rescue specific error so no need for begin/rescue/end block inside of the method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This way you won't even enter your validating function.
Take a look at [conditional validations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#conditional-validation)

```
validate :mobile_phone_number, unless: proc { phone_number.blank? }
```

for those who dont like unless

```
validate :mobile_phone_number, if: proc { phone_number.present? }
```

Comment: Awesome. Seems like this way is more rails-esque and more explicit in general: read less code to figure out what's going on. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

At the beginning of the begin:

```
if self.phone_number.blank?
   return true
end
```

Comment: Beautiful, thank you! Had tried something like in rails console and worked no problem. Need to brush up on my understanding of exceptions.